# how to add image for fgcolor in jquery knob

Tags: jquery, canvas, jquery-knob

I know jquery knob is canvas based. Still I want to know any other chances to add image for fgcolor and cursor in jquery knob. Like I need pointer image to drag. So any chances to acheive that??? correct me If I am wrong.

I want to make jquery knob like this
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-S2LYDIMKGJM/UkVTQLDDv6I/AAAAAAAAAV8/zRhIDdhM3dY/s1600/home.jpg

Experts kindly help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Over a year late, but this is how I did it:

https://jsfiddle.net/gp536mv1/

Basically I inserted a div

```
<div class="knob">
  <input class="knob" value="0" data-linecap="round" >
  <div id="soundSymbol"></div>
</div>
```

with `position:absolute`:

```
#soundSymbol{position: absolute; font-size: 500%; pointer-events:none;}
```

and set the top and left of the div inside jquery knob's "draw" function

```
$("input.knob").knob({
    'draw': function () {
        var degInRad = this.cv*Math.PI/180;
        $('#soundSymbol').css({top:this.xy-this.radius*Math.cos(degInRad)-50, left: this.xy+this.radius*Math.sin(degInRad)-30});
    }
});
```

Depending on the type of knob you are using (angleArc, angleOffset, etc.) the trigonometric formula would be different.

I hope it helps future readers!

Answer (score 0):

**You can set a custom cursor using CSS:**

So if you created your jQueryKnob like this:

```
$(".yourKnobClass").knob();
```

You can change the cursor to your custom image like this:

```
$('.yourKnobClass').css( 'cursor', 'url(yourCustomCursor.png), auto' );
```